# How can I replace a data with iTextSharp in an existing PDF?

Tags: itext

How can I replace a data  with iTextSharp in an existing PDF?

i have a existing pdf. iwant to replace the text username in the pdf with my name.

using iTextsharp.

Answer (score 2):

You can't modify text in an existing PDF with iTextSharp. You could fill form fields, stamp it, merge two pages into one but you cannot modify text.

Comment: Not without a whole bunch of PDF-Fu, no.  It's _possible_, it's just Really Hard.  If you're willing to 'overwrite' instead of 'replace', and know where it is, then you're back in the land of "do-able".  You can even use iText-sharp to find the name... probably.